Training process with the default Spacy configuration file does not produce any log output
My config.cfg is generated according to the instructions provided at Spacy Quickstart
I run the train command:python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train .\train.spacy --paths.dev .\dev.spacy 
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = "pytorch"
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["transformer","ner"]
batch_size = 128
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}
vectors = {"@vectors":"spacy.Vectors.v1"}

[components]

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
incorrect_spans_key = null
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.ner_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = false
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerListener.v1"
grad_factor = 1.0
pooling = {"@layers":"reduce_mean.v1"}
upstream = "*"

[components.transformer]
factory = "transformer"
max_batch_items = 4096
set_extra_annotations = {"@annotation_setters":"spacy-transformers.null_annotation_setter.v1"}

[components.transformer.model]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3"
name = "roberta-base"
mixed_precision = false

[components.transformer.model.get_spans]
@span_getters = "spacy-transformers.strided_spans.v1"
window = 128
stride = 96

[components.transformer.model.grad_scaler_config]

[components.transformer.model.tokenizer_config]
use_fast = true

[components.transformer.model.transformer_config]

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
accumulate_gradient = 3
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null
before_update = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_padded.v1"
discard_oversize = true
size = 2000
buffer = 256
get_length = null

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001

[training.optimizer.learn_rate]
@schedules = "warmup_linear.v1"
warmup_steps = 250
total_steps = 20000
initial_rate = 0.00005

[training.score_weights]
ents_f = 1.0
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0
ents_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]

There are no logs generated during the training process:
=========================== Initializing pipeline ===========================
Some weights of the model checkpoint at roberta-base were not used when initializing RobertaMode
l: ['lm_head.bias', 'lm_head.decoder.weight', 'lm_head.dense.bias', 'lm_head.dense.weight', 'lm_
head.layer_norm.weight', 'lm_head.layer_norm.bias']

This IS expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model trained o
n another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification m
odel from a BertForPreTraining model).
This IS NOT expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model that
you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a Be
rtForSequenceClassification model).
✔ Initialized pipeline

============================= Training pipeline =============================
ℹ Pipeline: ['transformer', 'ner']
ℹ Initial learn rate: 0.0
E    #       LOSS TRANS...  LOSS NER  ENTS_F  ENTS_P  ENTS_R  SCORE

The initial_rate specified in the config file is 0.00005, however, during training, it displays 'Initial learn rate: 0.0'.  Is this inconsistency the cause of the problem?
I want to know how to make training process normal.
